# Why ng-class is not updating using setTimeout? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a function 'highlightBookmark' that should change the background color of a list item after 2 seconds. But it doesn't work!!!
It changes 'li' background only if the function is called by click event. It doesn't change it automatically after time is out, even if it actually calls the function.

Here is my code:

Controller.js

```
//markers
$scope.markers = [
    {
        time: 9.5,
        text: "Bookmark 1",
        class: false
    },
    {
        time: 106,
        text: "Bookmark 2",
        class: false
    }
]

$scope.currentBookmark = -1;

function highlightBookmark(index) {
    $scope.markers[index].class = true;
}

var interval = setInterval(checkTime, 100);

function checkTime(){
    if(Math.floor(player.currentTime()) == 2){
        highlightBookmark(1)
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}

$scope.jumpTo = function (index) {
    highlightBookmark(index);
}
```

The highlight function, takes in an integer, looks for object at that position and updates set 'class' parameter to true. Example, if I pass number 1 to the function, it will look for object at index 2 and set the 'class property' to be true.

Then, after 2 seconds I want to call the highlightBookmark function. IT IS CALLED but it doesn't update the class, thus the background doesn't update.

I call the same with click event and it works.

HTML file

```
<ul id = "bookmarkList">
    <li ng-repeat="bookmark in markers" ng-class="{'active': bookmark.class}" ng-click="jumpTo($index)">{{bookmark.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

This li has the ng-class property that I want to change after 2 seconds.

Here is a link to a similar code I did on codepen. It changes button color on click, but doesn't change on setTimeout even if method is called

https://codepen.io/Octtavius/pen/wgzORv

Could somebody help with this simple issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vanilla `setInterval` function doesn't update scope variables. Try with the `$interval` API by Angular:

```
var interval = $interval(checkTime, 100);

function checkTime(){
    if(Math.floor(player.currentTime()) == 2){
        highlightBookmark(1)
        interval.cancel();
    }
}
```

1. Notice `clearInterval(interval)` changes to `interval.cancel()`
2. Also don't forget to inject it as dependency.
3. Fair point by charlietfl: Also cancel the interval if the scope gets destroyed.

Place this inside your controller:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function( event ) {
    interval.cancel( timer );
});
```

More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: might also want to cancel it when scope is destroyed

Answer (score 1):

setInteral and setTimeout run outside of the angular digest cycle, so they will not be properly picked up by Angular.

Consider using the $timeout object in your controller -- this gives you the timeout functionality but allows angular to keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider use angular `$timeout` instead of `setInverval` or `setTimeout`.

### Because:

1. This functions don't `$digest` the `$scope` variables;
2. `$timeout` in this case requires less memory to do the exactly same thing that `$interval` would do.

---

So, this part of your controller will look like this:

```
//markers
$scope.markers = [
    {
        time: 9.5,
        text: "Bookmark 1",
        class: false
    },
    {
        time: 106,
        text: "Bookmark 2",
        class: false
    }
]

$scope.currentBookmark = -1;

function highlightBookmark(index) {
    $scope.markers[index].class = true;
}

$timeout(checkTime, 2000);

function checkTime(){
    highlightBookmark(1);
}

$scope.jumpTo = function (index) {
    highlightBookmark(index);
}
```

---

Remember to inject the `$timeout` as a dependency in your controller.

### P.S.

This code will mark a default after 2 seconds, you don't give enough details so I can know what the `player` is doing. So if you want to improve this, give more details and we can make it happen.

You should consider use "controller as". Here is a link to John Papa's article about it. https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

And if you want to `toggle` the background on click event you should use this code. Cause the one you did is only adding the background, but not removing from the others `li`. To do this we need to modify the `html` and the `controller` a little bit:

---

```
<div ng-app="classApp" ng-controller="classCtrl">
   <ul id = "bookmarkList">
    <li ng-repeat="bookmark in markers" ng-class="{'active': selectedMarker === bookmark}" ng-click="jumpTo(bookmark)">{{bookmark.text}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
$scope.selectedMarker = null;

function highlightBookmark(marker) {
   $scope.selectedMarker = marker;
}

$timeout(checkTime, 2000);

function checkTime(){
   highlightBookmark($scope.markers[0])
}

$scope.jumpTo = function (marker) {
   highlightBookmark(marker);
}
```

Cya.

Answer (score 0):

```
var classApp = angular.module('classApp', []);

classApp.controller('classCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.isActive = false;
    $scope.activeButton = function () {
        $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
    }

    function checkTime() {
        $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
    }

    $timeout(checkTime, 2000)
});
```